# C# metro app Bluetooth rfcomm

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, microsoft-metro, rfcomm

I'm making a app that connects to bluetooth devices. When I search for devices I get

**Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation** in the list box, but I want the device name.

The code I'm using is:"Search for devices"

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
            RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
```

Add devices to list box.

```
foreach (var device in devices)
            {

                DevicesListBox.Items.Add(device);
            }
```

If I change *DevicesListBox.Items.Add(device)* to *DevicesListBox.Items.Add(**device.name**)* I get **System.String** error.

Connecting to the device

```
var serviceInfo = (DeviceInformation)DevicesListBox.SelectedItem;

        try
        {
            rfcommService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(serviceInfo.Id);

            if (rfcommService != null)
            {
                socket = new StreamSocket();
                await socket.ConnectAsync(
                    rfcommService.ConnectionHostName,
                    rfcommService.ConnectionServiceName)
```

Comment: If you found a solution to this yet, I'm interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not null-Checking the Device.Name. You're unfortunately likely to get this kind of error. I've seen about 4 devices in my office that don't have names and were causing me some headache. Hopefully you got this solved!